# How to play sound in setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, audio

I am trying to refresh the page and compare it to check if the table data is modified or not after interval..& if modified then play a notification sound.The notification sound duration is of **60 sec**.But it play the sound for just a **second** & then it refresh the page.How can i pause the execution until the sound has been fully played & then continue.

```
var foo = setInterval(function(){
window.location.reload(1);
var myTable = document.getElementById('admin_id');
var rows =  myTable.rows;
var firstRow = rows[0];debugger;
    try {
     if ($.cookie('new') === null || $.cookie('new') === "" )
       {        
    $.cookie("new", firstRow["cells"][10].innerText);
    }
    else
    {   
    var cookieValue = $.cookie("new");      
    if(cookieValue!=firstRow["cells"][10].innerText){       
        $.cookie("new", firstRow["cells"][10].innerText);
        //clearInterval(foo);
        document.getElementById('id_audio').play();             
    }

    }
    }catch(err){alert(err.message);};
  }, 1800000);

 //Audio TAg Code
<audio id="id_audio" src="sound.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the page, everything in the page (including your code) is thrown away and **replaced** by the new page. The code above after the `reload` call runs briefly (still on the old page), and when it returns the browser terminates any ongoing processes the page is doing and loads the page fresh. Your code does **not** wait at the `reload` for the page to reload and then keep going.

Instead of what you're doing, have your code that checks for the `new` cookie run on page load. Then when you're reloading, just reload — your code will run on the reloaded page (on load).

If you don't want the code run on every page load, but just on reloads, set a flag in session storage before reloading and check it on load:

When reloading:

```
sessionStorage.reloadedAt = Date.now();
location.reload(1);
```

Then on load:

```
if (+sessionStorage.reloadedAt > Date.now() - 30000) {
    // Do your checks
}
```

3000ms = three seconds, adjust as appropriate.